# Difference between LookupEdit and ComboBoxEdit in DevExpress

Tags: devexpress, controls

Hi all,
      I want to know what is the difference between 2 controls in DevExpress. Those are `LookupEdit` and `ComboBoxEdit`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LookupEdit is an editor which obtains items for its DropdownWindow from the underlying DataSource.  I.e. it required you to set the ValueMember, DisplayMember and DataSource properties.

ComboBoxEdit obtains items from its Items collection.

The standard WinForms comboBox is a mix of these two editors and can work in both modes.

Also, here is a useful article:

[Can I bind the XtraEditor's ComboBox to a datatable?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A65.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is tangential to the OP question but addresses an similar issue that has caused me a lot of trouble.

Note that unlike the winforms combobox control, the DevExpress LookupEdit does NOT automatically synchronize the currency manager.

Although, you can do this manually:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A2275.aspx